# Regex not in group

Tags: c#, regex

Iam trying to get some text from a EDI file, with Regex. I got this string/text:

```
UNA:+.? '
UNB+UNOC:3+5790000120420:14+5790000181872:14+991111:1850+KuvertNr1234'
UNH+BrevNr5678+CONTRL:D:93A:ZZ:C0230Q+CTL02'
UCI+MEDREF01095+5790000181872:14+5790000120420:14+4'
UCM+1111MAN01095+MEDREF:D:93A:UN:H0130R+4'
FTX+VER+P00++EDI-brev med nummeret 1111MAN01095, afsendt 11/11 1999 kl 18.46 har \:ikke kunnet modtages. Horsens Sygehus, laboratoriet kan ikke modtage \:sygehushenvisninger. :Med venlig hilsen: IT-Hotline. Horsens Sygehus.Telefon 12345678.'UNT+5+BrevNr5678'UNZ+1+KuvertNr1234'
```

And i need the `FTX` text. And i got this regex for it: `FTX\+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})\+([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\+\+(.*?)'`

But in the Edifact, ? escapes ', so if i add ?' to the text

```
UNA:+.? '
UNB+UNOC:3+5790000120420:14+5790000181872:14+991111:1850+KuvertNr1234'
UNH+BrevNr5678+CONTRL:D:93A:ZZ:C0230Q+CTL02'
UCI+MEDREF01095+5790000181872:14+5790000120420:14+4'
UCM+1111MAN01095+MEDREF:D:93A:UN:H0130R+4'
FTX+VER+P00++EDI-brev med nummeret 1111MAN01095, afsendt 11/11 1999 kl 18.46 har \:ikke kunnet modtages. Horsens Sygehus, laboratoriet kan ikke modtage \:sygehushenvisninger. :Med venlig hilsen: IT-Hotline.?' Horsens Sygehus.Telefon 12345678.'UNT+5+BrevNr5678'UNZ+1+KuvertNr1234'
```

My regex stops at the ' char right after ?. How can i use the .*? but ignore the "?'" in the text?
The Edifact can either be with \n or as a long string without \n

Tried with: `FTX\+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})\+([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\+\+(.*?)'`

Comment: "*How can i use the `.*?` but ignore the `?` in the text?*" - Use `[^?]*?` (if you want to stop before the `?` and `'`, it can also be `[^?']*` then). See https://regex101.com/r/VN6ZEJ/1

Comment: I want it to stop at ', but not if the ' is escape by a ? in front of it.

Comment: Ok, so `FTX\+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})\+([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\+\+([^?']*(?:\?'[^?']*)*)`. Or `FTX\+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})\+([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\+\+(.*?)'(?<!\?')`

Comment: That works! but what is the different between the 2?

Comment: If i add 2 ?? in the text is stops also, can we fix that also?

Comment: What does "?? in the text is stops" mean? The match does not "stop" at `??`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VN6ZEJ/3).

Comment: If you add "??" just after "Telefon", then the text stops and the capure is not hte whole text.

Comment: [Nothing stops there](https://regex101.com/r/VN6ZEJ/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
FTX\+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})\+([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\+\+(.*?)'(?<!\?')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VN6ZEJ/2).

*Details*:

- `FTX\+` - `FTX+` string
- `([a-zA-Z]{2,4})` - Group 1: two to four ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `\+` - a `+` char
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})` - Group 2: three ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `\+\+` - a `++` string
- `(.*?)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than a newline char, as few as possible
- `'(?<!\?')` - a `'` char that is not preceded with a `?` char.

Comment: Could you explain, why you have chosen `'(?<!\?')` over simpler on the first glance `(?<!\?)'`? Is there some kind of performance boost in this case?

Comment: @markalex Pure performance reason. It is easier to check once a `'` found once, rather than check each position before `'`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to exclude matching `'` using a negated character class, and only match it when it is directly preceded by a question mark:

```
FTX\+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})\+([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\+\+([^']*(?:'(?<=\?.)[^']*)*)'
```

The last part `([^']*(?:'(?<=\?.)[^']*)*)` matches:

- `(` Capture group

  - `[^']*` Match optional chars other than `'`
  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `'(?<=\?.)` Match `'` and assert `?` before it using a positive lookbehind
    - `[^']*` Match optional chars other than `'`
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat
- `)` Close the capture group
- `'` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w4qfmn/1)